# Is it possible to create a new map in Google My Maps using your own website? If so, how can I do it?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-markers

I am developing a project where I need to create a new map every 24 hours. Doing this manually is impossible, so I am wondering if it's possible to do it remotely through my website.

I don't know how to even start with this, because I don't know what I'm doing.
My idea is to use the setInterval() function in javascript, but how will the actual creation of the map work? Doing it manually requires just clicking a button, so I Guess that my real question is how do I remotely click that button through my website, if possible.

Comment: you can start from here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start off with this [Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) tutorial on how to load the map programatically without clicking a button. The map will automatically load once the initMap() function is called.

To create a new map every 24 hours, as you've mentioned, you can use the [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) method of JavaScript to call the function that loads your map without clicking a button manually. Check out this sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u16o3vat/8/).

```
var map;

//execute the initMap function every 24 hours
var myInterval =  setInterval(initMap, 86400000);

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}
```

If your use-case really needs a button to be clicked before showing a map, you can refer to this another sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u16o3vat/11/) which automatically clicks the show map button every 24 hrs.

Hope this helps!